# Entando 6 Installation Issue

Tags: kubernetes, entando

I have been trying to install Entando 6 on my Mac following the instructions on http://docs.entando.com, however when deploying to Kubernetes I get an error with **quickstart-kc-deployer**. Has anyone managed to successfully go through with the installation?

[deployment failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSChe.jpg)

Also I am new to Kubernetes and trying to access any logs, however as of now I have not been able to access logs and understand a bit more what the root cause of the failure is. Help on that is also more than welcome as well.

Thanks.

Comment: First try to `describe` such failing `Pod` or `Deployment` and look at its `Events` section. You can run `kubectl describe pod <pod-name>`/`kubectl describe deployment <deployment-name>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in a local development environment the best bet would be to try the new instructions at [dev.entando.org](https://dev.entando.org/). If you're installing on a cloud Kubernetes provider try the updated instructions here.

I've reproduced them here for completeness:

Install Multipass (https://multipass.run/#install

Launch VM

`multipass launch --name ubuntu-lts --cpus 4 --mem 8G --disk 20G`

Open a shell `multipass shell ubuntu-lts`

Install k3s `curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -`

Download Entando custom resource definitions

```
curl -L -C - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/entando/entando-releases/v6.2.0/dist/qs/custom-resources.tar.gz | tar -xz
```

Create custom resources
`sudo kubectl create -f dist/crd`

Create namespace
`sudo kubectl create namespace entando`

Download Helm chart

```
curl -L -C - -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/entando/entando-releases/v6.2.0/dist/qs/entando.yaml
```

Configure access to your cluster

```
IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
sed -i "s/192.168.64.25/$IP/" entando.yaml
```

If you want to deploy on a cloud provider (EKS, AKS, GKE) then there are new instructions under the Configuration and Operations section at

https://dev.entando.org/next/tutorials